# for (post in [loop]) { post.tagMoreAppropriately(); }

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [loop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) tag is generic... like, very, very generic. Generic as in, if your code doesn't loop somewhere, it's probably not a computer program. Hence I'm nominating the [loop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) tag for burnination.

Numbers and stuff:

- As of 2016-04-06 there are [460 posts tagged with `loop`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/loop/info)
- At the same time, the language tags [associated with `loop` tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/467566) are basically... every language tag.
- Practically all code ever written uses loops in one form or another; therefore, all CR questions should be tagged with [loop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop), or none should.

What shall be done with this tag?

Comment: Alternatively, `(map tagMoreAppropriately [loop])` (but that might not be a loop, depending on your definition)

Answer (score 13):

Burnination is probably fine and the [iterator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iterator) tag probably suffices for the examples my previous answer references.

The tag is pretty terrible.

Answer (score 4):

Burnination is not fine.

I can think of at least two specific examples where the [loop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) tag is more than appropriate:

- [A general iterator to replace "non-standard" C-style for loops](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/124572/36366)
- [Swift replacement for C's for loop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/118445/36366)

These questions are actually *about* loops and loop mechanics, in the exact way that questions with the [string](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) tag are about strings, or questions with the [array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array) tag are about arrays (and those are probably both tags that equally need as much of a clean-up as [loop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop)).

Just because your code uses a loop doesn't mean the tag is appropriate.

Just because your primary concern with your code is about your loops doesn't mean the tag is appropriate.

But the two linked questions are perfect examples of the usefulness of the [loop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) tag.  The vast majority of questions tagged [loop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) probably do not need the tag and can be cleaned up rather than burning the tag.

As an alternative suggestion, I propose renaming the tag to [loop-mechanics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop-mechanics) in order to discourage it from being used willy-nilly left and right on all sorts of questions that just happen to have a loop in them, and then we clean the tag up.